# adding items on PHP shopping cart

Tags: php

If the same item was selected multiple time to be added to cart,the code that I am working on below adds another line on the display table for shopping cart instead of just updating the quantity of the same item.

I hope to just update the quantity of the item and not display it again on the cart

```
<?php $total = 0; ?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){ ?>
<?php foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $row): ?>
<?php if($row['qty'] != 0): ?>
<tr>
  <td class="text-center"><strong><?php echo 
    $row['product'];?></strong></td>
  <td class="text-center">
    <?php echo $row['price'];?>
  </td>
  <td class="text-center">
    <form action="cart/data.php?q=updatecart&id=<?php echo 
    $row['proID'];?>" method="POST">
      <input type="number" name="qty" value="<?php echo 
    $row['qty'];?>" min="0" style="width:50px;" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
    </form>
  </td>
  <?php $itotal = $row['price'] * $row['qty']; ?>
  <td class="text-center">
    <font class="itotal">
      <?php 
    echo $itotal; ?>
    </font>
  </td>
  <td class="text-center"><a href="cart/data.php?
    q=removefromcart&id=<?php echo $row['proID'];?>"><i class="fa fa-times-
    circle fa-lg text-danger removeproduct"></i></a></td>
</tr>
<?php $total = $total + $itotal;?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $_SESSION['totalprice'] = isset($_SESSION['totalprice']) ? 
    $_SESSION['totalprice'] : $total; ?>
```

Comment: What does data.php? Your problem will be there, not in this code.

Comment: it has the function     function addtocart($product, $price, $qty){
        $cart = array(
            'proID' => $_SESSION['proID'],
            'product' => $product,
            'price' => $price,
            'qty' => $qty
        );
        $_SESSION['proID'] = $_SESSION['proID'] + 1;
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$cart); 
        
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Run a check with the product ID while adding to card,

If the productID is already in the cart
  Add 1 to the quantity

Else 
  Just add to cart

Also try cleaning up your code, its difficult to understand.